# Image is shifted when displayed in iPad-Pro in landscape mode, when using Babel transpiler

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a Javascript script that displays an image (width x height resolution is 2160 x 3840).
When displayed in iPad-Pro in landscape mode, the image is shifted down.
The example code in [here](https://codepen.io/avnerm/pen/vYERvqK) demonstrates the problem.

I checked the image display in various devices and browsers (see the table below)
The image is displayed ok all the devices (laptop, Macbook, Android mobile, iPhone8) but not in iPad-Pro.
(for the laptop, and Macbook devices, the image displays ok (without shift) in the native orientation, and in emulation of landscape, and portrait mode (via *Safari -> Develop -> Responsive Design Mode*))

Note that to run the example in Apple Device I needed to transpile the code using Babel.
I tested the example in iPad-Pro in multiple browsers (Chrome, Safari, and Firefox).
With transpiling, the image is shifted (figure1).
(but the same transpiled code runs ok on iPhone8 (figure2))

How can I fix or further debug this problem?
Thanks

[image: table1]
[image: figure1 - image shifted in landscape orientation]
[image: figure1 - image NOT shifted in portrait orientation]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ############################ -->
    <!-- using jsdelivr, with transpile -->
    <!-- NOT OK - image is shifted -->
    <!-- ############################ -->
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Construction Overlay App">
    <meta name="author" content="Avner M.">
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src 'self' blob: https:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
       -->
<title>With transpile landscape image shifted</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@2.2.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastr@2.1.4/build/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/avnermosh/example12_ipad_landscape_image_not_centered_properly@master/example12_style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid-container1"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/regenerator-runtime@0.13.1/runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/avnermosh/example12_ipad_landscape_image_not_centered_properly@master/build/bundle2.js"></script>

    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastr@2.1.4/build/toastr.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by upgrading iOS to 14.0.1.
This solved the problem, and the image is no longer shifted.
It now displays properly in landscape and portrait orientations.